# Caesar cypher indexing

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

Can someone briefly explain me what happens in this line:

```
new_word += alphabet[alphabet.index(i.downcase) - num]
```

new_word = current state of new_word variable + what?

This is whole program:

```
def cipher(word, num)
alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a.concat(('A'..'Z').to_a)
new_word = ""

word.each_char do |i|
  if !alphabet.include?(i)
    new_word +=i
  else
    new_word += alphabet[alphabet.index(i.downcase) - num]  
  end
end

return new_word.downcase.capitalize
end

puts cipher("Apples? and Oranges!", 2)
```

Comment: There's the String#tr method that was basically built for this. No need to convert to unicode or whatever. I built a cipher using #tr. Let me know if you'd like to see what I did. You'll find it more efficient and reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_word` is a `String`, so the value on the right will be appended to it. The expression `alphabet[alphabet.index(i.downcase) - num]` is just an inefficient way of determining a character that is shifted `num` places in the alphabet.

`alphabet` is an `Array` containing the character values corresponding to the letters of the alphabet, starting with lowercase letters and then followed by uppercase letters.

The [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-index) method in this case finds the index of the first occurence of the character value `i` in `alphabet`. This index is then decreased by `num`. The character corresponding to this new position is finally looked up in `alphabet`, and the result is appended to `new_word`.

Note also that the result will „wrap around“ in the sense that if the new index is negative, the array will be indexed from the back, resulting in the capital letters if `num` is not too large. Those potential uppercase letters will be downcased in `new_word.downcase.capitalize`.

---

The `downcase` part is strange, because it means that the „cipher“ is not invertible. Note also that this will not work as you might expect if `num`s absolute value is so large that the lookup is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It's adding to the new word the letter in the alphabet which is represented by (alphabet.index(i.downcase) - num).

i.downcase just converts the letter to lowercase if it wasn't already.

alphabet.index finds the place in the alphabet where i exists.

The num subtraction is the cipher. It changes the letter that would be added by modifying the index in alphabet where the letter is found. A num of 1 would change 'b's into 'a's, because 'a's come before 'b' in the given alphabet.

So it takes the letter, converts it into lowercase, then an array index, modifies that index by num and adds the letter that that new index represents back onto the word.